# python: comparing equivalent coordinates

Tags: python, mysql, math, sympy

I am doing a maths quiz for my coursework based around differentiation and integration using python 3. I'm finding it difficult to check if the answer, typed in by the user, is correct. I'm currently using the code below. However, if the user types in answer but in a different order it is treated as incorrect. for example if the answer was (2,4) but I typed in (4/2,4) it would be treated as incorrect despite both answers being correct. I've tried using sympify but it isnt working. How would I overcome this issue?

```
    def Question4(self):
        QID = 109
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password = "", host = "")
        mycursor = conn.cursor()
        #mysql query 
        query = """
        SELECT 
            QText, QAnswer, Marks
        FROM 
            QuestionInfo.Question
        WHERE 
            QID = %s
        """
        mycursor.execute(query, (QID, ))
        Question4, Answer4, Mark4 = mycursor.fetchone()
        self.Answer4 = str(Answer4)
        self.Mark4 = Mark4
        self.next_question.clicked.connect(self.HandleQuestion4)

    def HandleQuestion4(self):
        #for validation
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure this is your final answer?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
            QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes)
        #get users answer in a sympy state
        self.UAnswer4 = self.Answer.text().replace("^", "**")

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            if sympify(self.UAnswer4) == sympify(self.Answer4):
                self.score = self.score + self.Mark4
            else:
                self.score = self.score + 0
            self.Question5()
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code, including how `self.Answer` is defined, and how `FDiffAnswer` is defined?

Comment: Can't you use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)? You can then compare the values rather than the textual representation.

Comment: No, he's using the sympy library; he wants to compare values symbolically rather than numerically. `eval` will compute a numeric value where it can, and it won't work with nonnumeric expressions like `x^2`.

Comment: i've posted more of the code if this will help

Comment: Can you give some examples of both correct and incorrect answers that are not well recognized?

Comment: As to your example, for me `print(sympify('(4/2,4)') == sympify('(2,4)'))` prints `True` -- are you sure `'(4/2,2)'` and `'(2,4)'` are your inputs?

Comment: okay currently if the answer is equation based equivalent answers are accepted. e.g 5*x**2 is the same as 10/2*x**4/2. But the issue is when the answer is coordinate based. For example, if the answer is (2,0) only (2,0) will be accepted not other answers like (4/2,0)

Comment: In this line `self.UAnswer4 = self.Answer.text().replace("^", "**")` do you mean `self.UAnswer4 = self.UAnswer.text().replace("^", "**")`?  Note the change from "Answer" to "UAnswer" on the right side of the assignment.

Comment: no, there was a Qlineedit called Answer.text() I changed it to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting only numbers then you can use S (short for sympify) on the string. Otherwise you might need parse_expr and/or other string processing to to handle additional syntax like implied multiplication and "^" for exponentiation (see sympy.parsing.sympy_parser):

```
>>> S('4/2,2')
(2, 2)
```